# Can't move after changing the player's position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a teleport. The player hits the teleport, then goes to the other teleport. However when he reaches there, he can't move ...

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(hitted1){
        posi = new Vector3(42.49f, 0.5f, 163.8f); 
        player.transform.position = posi;
        //hitted1 = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if(other.name == "FPSController"){
        Debug.Log("player hit tele1");
        hitted1 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to comment out hitted1 = false on purpose? If not, what happens when it is uncommented?

Comment: Chase: When uncommented comes another problem where the player return to its original position...

Comment: @gustavo302 explain the other problem

Comment: Is it maybe just calling the same position over and over again every frame. Can you debug and put the breakpoint on the if(hitted1) line. Run it once or twice and one time stop on the break point on change the values assigned to new Vector(42.49f, 0.5f, 163.8f) to something different and see if the player position changes.

Comment: Jeroen van Langen: As i said. The player return to the first teleport, when the hitted1 is uncommented. Since he will only change position after hitting the first teleport.

Comment: Chase: Unfortunately i can't debug... Always when i download vs code it just doesn't work. Anyway, i don't have experience using debug as well...

Comment: Are you sure that the player object isn't stuck into some collider after its teleported using `transform.position`?

Comment: If un-commenting that line causes another problem, then you have a problem somewhere else. Because as-is your code is preventing the player from moving because you constantly set its position once they teleport. We can't solve the original issue because you didn't include the details for the other issue.

Comment: Nitro557: I'm. I have removed the tele2 collider and the player collider as well and didn't help...

Comment: Is this all of your update code?  are you setting the position elsewhere as well?  I agree with the others that with hitted commented out you are forcing the position every call to Update... when you uncomment it, is there other code that then sets the position back to where you were by chance?

Comment: iamJP:  The player should be able to go from tele1 to tele2, and from tele2 to tele1. Thats the idea. there's no code from  tele2 to tele1, because i wanted to test the first one which is tele1 to tele2. My english is not the very best, so if you didn't get it, please tell me. The if(hitted1) is in update.

Comment: @gustavo302 How does the player move?  I suspect that that code is what causes the player to move back after teleporting.  I cannot know for sure without seeing that code.

Comment: iamJP: that can be probably the thing here, because it wans't me who did the code for the player.... Anyway, thanks for helping guys... I gotta go to college...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using a FPSController from Standard Assets. If it's true, then that FPSController object contains the CharacterController component. This component may prevent changing object's location via `transform.position` (in other words, location will be changed to a specific one, but after that the object will return to its previous location that was set before changing `transform.position`).

As you described, the FPSController object just freezing after it was teleported to a new position. It's because when value of `hitted1` changes to `true`, `player.transform.position = posi;` running each `Update()` cause `hitted1` value stays in `true`.

But, when you trying to uncomment `hitter1 = false`, the FPSController object returning to its previous position. Its because the CharacterController stay enabled while changing location via `transform position`.

**Try to:**

```
CharacterController controller;


    void Start() {
    controller = player.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }  
    void Update()
    {
        if(hitted1){
            posi = new Vector3(42.49f, 0.5f, 163.8f);
            controller.enabled = false;
            player.transform.position = posi;
            controller.enabled = true;
            hitted1 = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the answer to the problem you asked about. Your code is continually calling the same teleport code over and over therefore it moves the character the first time but keeps putting him in same position after the initial Update every frame. In the comment you said uncommenting hitted1 = false; causes other problems and that might be true. But this will fix the movement issue. Fix that and then work on the problem that arises from having it uncommented.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(hitted1){
        posi = new Vector3(42.49f, 0.5f, 163.8f); 
        player.transform.position = posi;
        hitted1 = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if(other.name == "FPSController"){
        Debug.Log("player hit tele1");
        hitted1 = true;
    }
}
```